# Assigning values to field based on values in other field using Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a table with two fields A and B, and i want fill field B with "some values" from field A:

FieldA:
123456_CC;
123_D;
1234567_AB;
123456768_F

I just need the "text" that is associated with the value of the field

FieldB:
CC;
D;
AB;
F

What expression to create this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all of your row values are in the form `chunkA_chunkB`, you can use the following expression in the field calculator:

```
!yourField!.split("_")[1]
```

This method actually breaks the string into a list of selectable items.  To illustrate, in the python interpreter:

```
>>> row1 = '123456_CC'
>>> row1.split("_")
['123456', 'CC']
```

And to select just the second item in the list:

```
>>> row1.split("_")[1]
'CC'
```